# Check if a value is present in enum or not

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift3

Following is my enum

```
enum HomeDataType: String, CaseIterable {
  case questions           = "questions"
  case smallIcons          = "smallIcons"
  case retailers           = "retailers"
  case products            = "products"
  case banners             = "banners"
  case single_product      = "single_product"
  case single_retail       = "single_retail"
  case categories          = "categories"
  case airport             = "All_Airport"
  case single_banner       = "single_banner"
  case none                = "none"
}
```

Want to check if a value is present in enum or not? How to do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You meant that if "banners" is a valid value? You could do `HomeDataType.init(rawValue: "banners")` and check if it's `nil` or not. Or you have a `HomeDataType` with multiple possibles values, then you want an OptionSet, but might need others changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply try to initialize a new enumeration case from your string or check if all cases contains a `rawValue` equal to your string:

```
let string = "categories"

if let enumCase = HomeDataType(rawValue: string) {
    print(enumCase)
}

if HomeDataType.allCases.contains(where: { $0.rawValue == string }) {
    print(true)
}
```

Comment: My preferred solution. You do need to make sure the enum is CaseIterable though, check code in question when in doubt on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize enum using rawValue will return an optional, so you can try to unwrap it

```
if let homeDataType = HomeDataType (rawValue: value) {
    // Value present in enum
} else {
    // Value not present in enum
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add static method to your enum, which attempts to create instance of the enum and returns if it succeeded or not

```
 static func isPresent(rawValue: String) -> Bool {
    return HomeDataType(rawValue: rawValue) != nil
 }

 HomeDataType.isPresent(rawValue: "foobar") // false
 HomeDataType.isPresent(rawValue: "banners") // true
```

Comment: You can extend `RawRepresentable` and create a generic method `extension RawRepresentable {` `static func contains(_ rawValue: RawValue) -> Bool {` `Self.init(rawValue: rawValue) != nil` `}` `}`

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest solution. You don't need `CaseIterable` protocol for that.

```
guard let type = HomeDataType(rawValue: string) else { return }
switch type {
    case .questions:
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

solutions relying on init returning nil are bad because:

[Enum initialized with a non-existent rawValue does not fail and return nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034190/enum-initialized-with-a-non-existent-rawvalue-does-not-fail-and-return-nil)

swift team do not document this behavior anywhere and it shows how bad language and the team are